# Complete ReCaptcha from another domain

Tags: php, curl, cookies, recaptcha

Let me start by stating this : **I absolutely do not wish to bypass the captcha**.

I am using a particular website (lets call it "**Swidili**"), that shows a list of websites based on a theme and ordered by votes they got from the users. These votes are limited by IP adress and time (one per hour).

I wish to gift something to the users of my own website (lets call it "**Badada**") that vote for my website on **Swidili**. My issue is that I have no way of knowing if a user really voted. There is a cookie response that you get when you vote (vote=y) that lasts an hour (or until you can vote again).

Obviously, I can't read the users cookies from another domain. There is also no API made available by the owner of **Swidili**. I tried contacting him, but he does not seem to wish to answer me. Since it has now been a couple of months, I'm trying to find another way.

The solution that I thought of would be to show the captcha on my website, and then send with curl the result of that captcha. That way, the user is able to vote, and I can check if the vote is real by getting the cookies back from curl. Unfortunately, that does not seem to be possible, since ReCaptcha2 is limited to specified domains.

I have asked other webmasters, and they seem to have found a solution, but refuse to share it with me. I was wondering if there could be another way to get this cookie. Am I doomed ?

Comment: Yeah I don't believe there is a way you can do this without some integration on Swidili's part. It sounds like those "webmasters" aren't entirely telling you the truth.

Comment: I kind of doubt Swidili's webmaster has accepted to add them to the recaptcha's authorised domains. They don't have the captcha anyway. I think they get the cookie another way, just don't know how. I'm still trying to contact the webmaster, but I think I'll just give up. I don't see any solution.

Comment: I'm assuming you know of the same origin policy? There is no way they can read the cookies of Swidili from a different domain. This is unless someone on Swidili's part has purposely enabled access to this information. I recommend checking out this post: [SOP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8264/why-is-the-same-origin-policy-so-important)

Comment: I know of it, that's pretty much why I am stuck. I know that I'm not supposed to have access to Swidili's cookies. Thank you for the link tho, it was very instructive. I'll keep on messaging the webmaster until he answers.